Error while creating a database in .NET 6
During the editing of ContractTypeOne and ContractTypeTwo models, I received this error:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ContractTypeTwos_ContractTypeOnes_ContractTypeOneId' on table 'ContractTypeTwos' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I would like the ContractTypeTwo to be removed after removing ContractTypeOne. But I don't want to delete Contract after removing ContractTypeOne.
namespace ContractAppAPI.Models
{
    public class Contract
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ContractNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfConclusion { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Contractor { get; set; }
        public string Signatory { get; set; }
        public Boolean HasPdf { get; set; }
        public ContractTypeOne ContractTypeOne { get; set; }
        public ContractTypeTwo ContractTypeTwo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ContractPdf> ContractPdfs { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AnnexToTheContract> AnnexToTheContracts { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContractTypeOne
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ContractTypeTwo> ContractTypeTwos { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContractTypeTwo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ContractTypeOneId { get; set; }
        public ContractTypeOne ContractTypeOne { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<ContractTypeOne>()
    .HasMany(cto => cto.ContractTypeTwos)
    .WithOne(ctt => ctt.ContractTypeOne)
    .HasForeignKey(ctt => ctt.ContractTypeOneId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<ContractTypeTwo>()
    .HasOne(ctt => ctt.ContractTypeOne)
    .WithMany(cto => cto.ContractTypeTwos)
    .HasForeignKey(ctt => ctt.ContractTypeOneId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

namespace ContractAppAPI.Models
{
    public class AnnexToTheContract
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AnnexNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfConclusion { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Contractor { get; set; }
        public string Signatory { get; set; }
        public Boolean HasPdf { get; set; } = false;
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Pdf> Pdfs { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ContractAppAPI.Models
{
    public class ContractPdf
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? File { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ContractAppAPI.Models
{
    public class Pdf
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? File { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public int AnnexToTheContractId { get; set; }
        public AnnexToTheContract AnnexToTheContract { get; set; }
    }
}


Please try to find the numerous questions on this topic. This is asked multiple times a week.

This ensures that Contract entities persist even if their related ContractTypeOne or ContractTypeTwo are removed.
modelBuilder.Entity<ContractTypeOne>()
    .HasMany(cto => cto.ContractTypeTwos)
    .WithOne(ctt => ctt.ContractTypeOne)
    .HasForeignKey(ctt => ctt.ContractTypeOneId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
    .HasOne(c => c.ContractTypeOne)
    .WithMany(cto => cto.Contracts)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContractTypeOneId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
    .HasOne(c => c.ContractTypeTwo)
    .WithMany(ctt => ctt.Contracts)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContractTypeTwoId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Also add this properties in main Contract class:
public int ContractTypeOneId { get; set; }
public int ContractTypeTwoId { get; set; }


Still is the same error...

i added this 2 properties in main class and tested locally and it  runs migration without errors

I have more models. Is it important?

Aftere removing last migrations, I have other error.
'FK_Contracts_ContractTypeTwos_ContractTypeTwoId' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
